# How do I implement efficient file upload to device over RS-232

Tags: c#, serial-port

I need to upload a file to a target platform over RS-232 protocol.

The input is a file (which has the memory address, the no. of bytes and the data to be written to the device memory). Since I am doing a block write through RS-232 I have followed this approach. But are there efficient ways to implement the below scheme as I am starting to code in C# and also in case I wish to show the download progress bar (based on the number of bytes written vs the total bytes). Do I implement this in a separate thread and update in the GUI. Are there any performance issues seen if the file size goes large with this scheme?

Below is the code:

```
private void DownloadToDevice(String file_path)
{
     FileData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file_path);

     StartAddress = BitConverter.ToUInt32(FileData, 12);
     StartAddress = FileData.ElementAt(12);

     NumOfBytes = BitConverter.ToUInt32(FileData, 16);
     NumOfBytes = FileData.ElementAt(16);

     Block = FileData.Skip(20).Take((int)NumOfBytes).ToArray();
     WriteBlock(StartAddress, Block, Block.Length);
}

private void WriteBlock(UInt32 Address, byte[] Data, int val)
{
    String command2 = "";
    UInt32 Data2;

    String command1 = String.Format("wr {0}", Address.ToString("x").PadLeft(8, '0'));

    for (int i = 0; i <= val ; i= i + 4)
    {
        Data2 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(Data,i);
        command2 = string.Concat(command2, String.Format("{0} ", Data2.ToString("x").PadLeft(8, '0')));
    }

    command1 = string.Concat(command1," ", command2,"\r");
    m_SP.Write(command1);
}
```

Comment: Also, is this conversion of bytes to 32-bit word alright to do this way or is there a better implementation possible?

Comment: In your GUI program, you should use `async`/`await` to allow the I/O to occur asynchronously, while still updating a progress bar and otherwise letting the GUI remain responsive. Retrieve the `SerialPort.BaseStream` object so that you can use the `Stream.WriteAsync()` method, which is awaitable. Computers are fast enough these days that performance per se is unlikely to be a concern; your device will be the bottleneck. For anything more specific than that, you need to actually _try_ something and then ask a less-broad question with _specific_ details and issues.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks for your inputs.  I am supposed to be continuing with VS2010, and can I still use this async/await approach.

Comment: You can use `async`/`await` with VS2010, but it will involve a little extra effort as you have to download the [Async CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9983) for VS2010. You may also use the older asynchronous API, also by retrieving `BaseStream`, such as `Stream.BeginWrite()`. It's more complicated to use, especially in the context of GUI code, but it would work just as well.

Comment: Serial ports are very slow, it just doesn't matter how you write your code.  It is always many thousands of times faster than it needs to be.  Focus instead on making sure your program operates correctly, test thoroughly.